# React + react-intersection-observer -- Impossible to set a new `options.root`

Tags: reactjs, intersection-observer

Trying to use react-intersection-observer, latest React.

I am trying to use the documented `options` to set a new `root` for the intersection calc engine. The problem is, it rejects my new root

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `options.root` supplied to `IntersectionVisible`, expected a ReactNode.
```

I am handing it a React ref I've created in an ancestor React component and handed it down to it via props and setting the props in the `<IntersectionVisible>` element to be:

```
options={{root: this.props.myref.current}}
```

this am I getting this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER**: *I haven't used the library but the answer is based-on the story book source.*

You need to pass the `ref` itself(`this.props.myref`), not the underlying DOM element, `this.props.myref.current`.

So instead of passing the DOM,

```
options={{root: this.props.myref.current}}
```

pass the reference itself.

```
options={{root: this.props.myref}}
```

I found a [story book](https://thebuilder.github.io/react-intersection-observer/?path=/story/intersection-observer--with-root), in which you see `root={node}`.
https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer/blob/master/stories/InView.story.tsx#L145

```
    <RootComponent>
      {node => (
        <ScrollWrapper>
          <InView
            threshold={0}
            // .. 
            root={node}
            onChange={action('Child Observer inview')}
          >
            {({ inView, ref }) => (
              <Header ref={ref} inView={inView}>
                Header is inside the root viewport: {inView.toString()}
              </Header>
            )}
          </InView>
        </ScrollWrapper>
      )}
    </RootComponent>
```

And `node` points to a reference itself.
https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer/blob/master/stories/Root/index.tsx#L29

```
class RootComponent extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
  state = {
    node: null,
  }

  handleNode = (node: HTMLElement | null) => {
    this.setState({
    //  this is a ref to `div` below.
      node,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
                      
      <div ref={this.handleNode} style={{ ...style, ...this.props.style }}>
        {/*
        // @ts-ignore */}
        {this.state.node ? this.props.children(this.state.node) : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that syntax Typescript or something? The handleNode function results in syntax errors when built on ES6/

Comment: Yes, it's written in typescript. It's same as `handleNode = (node) => { this.setState({ node }) }` in javascript.  It's an old way of assigning a ref, called [Callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs). Nowadays, you'd just create a ref using `React.createRef` (for class components) and `React.useRef` (for function components)